# T-SQL, Insert into with MAX()+1 in subquery doesn't increment, alternatives?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, batch-insert

I have a query where I need to "batch" insert rows into a table with a primary key without identity.

```
--TableA
--PK int (Primary key, no-identity)
--CustNo int
INSERT INTO TableA (PK,CustNo)
  SELECT (SELECT MAX(PK)+1 AS PK FROM TableA), CustNo
  FROM Customers
```

*(simplified example - please don't comment about possible concurrency issues :-))*

The problem is that it doesn't increment the PK "for each" processed row, and I get a primary key violation.

I know how to do it with a cursor/while loop, but I would like to avoid that, and solve it in a set-based kind of manner, if that's even possible ?

(running SQL Server 2008 Standard)

Comment: Why don't u make the column an identity column?

Comment: +1 @Cybernate - this is a terrible idea and if you had bothered to search on SO there are about 20 questions similar to this, each telling you why it's a bad idea.

Comment: Long story short: i would make an identity if i could :-) . @JNK i bothered allright, but it's my only option, and i want to solve it the best way possible. Also bear in mind i provided a simplified example.

Comment: Please elaborate on what is stopping you from making it an identity.  Yes there are many cases where there is a (better) alternative to identity but if there were no valid uses then identity would not be a feature in the first place.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
Declare @i int;

Select @i = max(pk) + 1 from tablea;

INSERT INTO TableA (PK, custno)
Select row_number() over(order by custno) + @i  , CustNo
FROM Customers
```

Answer (score 10):

+1 to Michael Buen, but I have one suggestion:

The table "tablea" can be empty, so we should write:

```
Select @i = isnull(max(pk),0) + 1 from tablea;
```

This will prevent a null error when trying to use this code.

Answer (score 4):

The problem as you have seen is that they all get the same row number, the max(PK) +1 is the same for every row.

Try convert it to be `Max(PK) + Row_number()`

I'm working on the basis as to why you know this is a bad idea etc, and your question is simplified for the purpose of getting an answer, and not how you would wish to solve the problem.

Comment: This will help. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845791/insert-multiple-rows-with-incremental-primary-key-sql

Answer (score 3):

You can;

```
;with T(NPK, CustNo) as (
  select row_number() over (order by CustNo), CustNo from Customers
)
insert into TableA (PK, CustNo)
  select NPK, custno from T
order by CustNo
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a suggestion for you buddy, a better practice on SQL says to use SEQUENCE, and guess what, it´s VERY easy to do it man, just copy and paste mine:

> CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_TABLEA AS INTEGER
>       START WITH 1
>       INCREMENT BY 1
>       MAXVALUE 2147483647
>       MINVALUE 1
>       NO CYCLE

and use like this:

> INSERT INTO TableA (PK,CustNo) VALUES (SEQ_TABLEA.NEXTVAL,123)

Hope this tip able to help ya!

Comment: Thanks for answering, but the original question was regarding SQL Server 2008, and SEQUENCE is only available for SQL Server 2012+